# unable to use OpenGLView in a Xamarin.Forms project for Android

Tags: visual-studio, opengl-es, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, opentk

I tried to use the code found here :
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.OpenGLView/

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using OpenTK.Graphics.ES30;
```

But When Debug starts, a Window opens (image attached) :
"Find Source"
And looks for the following file :
UncaughtExceptionHandler.cs
here :
/Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/UncaughtExceptionHandler.cs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zX3a.jpg)

When cancelled, the following error appears :
"Unhandled Exception:
Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec"

I guess my java or Android sdk or opentk.dll configuration is not ok.

I tried both using OpenTK.Graphics.ES20 and ES30.

Does anybody know a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Answer there: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/67226/i-cannot-use-openglview-in-a-xamarin-forms-project-for-android

It is an issue with virtual device or graphic card.